# What should FileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize be set to?

Tags: c#, buffer, filesystemwatcher

Just wondered if someone could give some general guidelines on what value I should give the `InternalBufferSize` property of a `FileSystemWatcher`.

I need to monitor several single files across multiple directories so I create one watcher per directory and then check to see if the file is one of the ones I'm monitoring. Since there can be several files in the same directory I can't use the `Filter` property unless I create one watcher per file rather than per directory. Not sure which is best, but either way, any advice would be welcome :)

Comment: Don't change it.  Implement the Error event to find out if you have a problem.  Then first consider changing your event handlers to make them faster, by for example handing off the work to a separate worker thread.

Comment: So I could listen to the Error event and double the buffer whenever I get a buffer error for example?

Answer (score 0):

Each `FileSystemWatcher` has it's own InternalBufferSize. If you monitor only single files you can set it to 1KB, it would me enough for ~16 per event. BUT as MSDN states, for Intel processors it's better to have InternalBufferSize dividible by 4KB.

Comment: I monitor only files particular files, but the watcher itself monitors the whole directory, since I can't use the Filter property.

Comment: How large are directories? And how often they change?

Comment: InternalBufferSize is documented as ignoring any values below 4096 and just using 4096.  4K should be the minimum you set it to.